# How to save an ArrayList in SugarORM?

Tags: android, sugarorm

I don't understand how to use SugarORM to save information from an array list.

```
 for (int i =0 ; i<price.size(); i++){
     List <OrdersSugarORM> ordersGo = new ArrayList<>();
     ordersGo.add(new OrdersSugarORM(article.get(i)));
     OrdersSugarORM.saveInTx(ordersGo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you think it is a good idea to save an arraylist of a single element repeatedly using the for loop.

Try this instead - build the list, *then* save it. (Using the correct object types, since you have not provided what `OrdersSugarORM` is...)

```
List <OrdersSugarORM> ordersGo = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < price.size(); i++){    
     ordersGo.add(new OrdersSugarORM(article.get(i)));
}
OrdersSugarORM.saveInTx(ordersGo);
```

And maybe you want `price.get(i)`, otherwise make sure that `price.size() == article.size()`

Comment: problem is that it don`t want to work with article.get (i) becouse he want String only and toString not helping at all

Comment: You have to edit your question to include the class definition. I can't guess at the parameters